# Reoccurring Incident(specific event_category) details between a time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to take reoccurring Incidents(specific event_category)details between a time frame from the given database where I have :
Event_Log table is linked with Asset Table and event_type table.
Event Type table is linked with Event category table.

Comment: What is the database - MySQL or SQL Server? Adjust your tags, please!

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012